# PayPal Payflow Pro error

Tags: php, api, sdk, paypal, payflowpro

I am using PayPal's Payflow pro API on a test account and no matter what, it tells me the field is incorrect. I am using PHP. This is the string being sent to them:

> USER=xxx&VENDOR=xxx&PARTNER=PayPal&PWD=xxx&TENDER=C&ACTION=A&TRXTYPE=R&PROFILENAME=JerProfile&PAYPERIOD=MONT&START=12152012&TERM=0&ACCT=4012888888881881&AMT=123.45&&BUTTONSOURCE=PF-CCWizard

And the response says

```
Array
(
    [RESULT] => 7
    [RPREF] => R1853E1E07BF
    [RESPMSG] => Field format error: Invalid or missing START/NEXTPAYMENTDATE field
)
```

And as you can see, I have specified a monthly pay period and the start date is in their format of mmddyyyy. Any help would be appreciated as this is driving me insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact order of the submitted variables is important:

```
        'TRXTYPE' => 'R',
        'PARTNER' => $API_Partner,
        'VENDOR' => $API_Vendor,
        'USER' => $API_User,
        'PWD' => $API_Password,
        'ACTION' => $action
```

And then any others required depending on which action. For the Create action, START must be tomorrow's date or a date in the future. Hope this helps somebody else having problems with PayPal's PayFlow API.

Answer (score 0):

What time zone are you in?  I see you're passing 12152012 for the date, and today is now the 15th...was it already the 15th where you're at when you ran this?

The documentation says...

> Beginning (or restarting) date for the recurring billing cycle used to
>   calculate when payments  should be made. **Use tomorrow’s date or a date
>   in the future.**

So as of now, maybe trying 12162012 would work..??

Comment: Although my timezone is ahead, the server is in the U.S and I'm using the date() function with strtotime('+1 day'). To test this idea I set it another day ahead, and then several, and it still gives me the same message.

Answer (score 0):

use

> START='12152012'

instead of `START=12152012`